# using str::find and find_first_of and last_of

Tags: c++, find

Im not sure if I used find_first of and last_of correctly, but what I want to do is that I need to print error when it finds _ on the beginning or at the end of my code, plus when it finds two or more _ next to each other, like this `lol___, lol__lol, _lol_, _lol, lol_,` and one more rule, _ cannot be in front of capital letter, like this `lol_Lol`

here is my code

```
             std::string::size_type n;
             std::string::size_type n2;
             std::string::size_type n3;
             std::string const ss = slovo;

             n  = ss.find('_');
             n2 = ss.find_first_of('_');
             n3 = ss.find_last_of('_');

            if (n2 == std::string::npos && n3 == std::string::npos) {
            cout << "chyba" << endl;
            }else if(n == std::string::npos){

                  string s = transform(slovo);
                  cout << s << endl;

                  }else{
                  string s = untransform(slovo);
                  cout << s << endl;

                  }
```

EDIT>

```
if ( !ss.empty() && ss.front() == '_' && ss.back() == '_' )
               {
                cout << "Chyba" << endl;
               } else {

                if ( ss.length() > 3 && ss.find( '__', 1, ss.length() - 2 ) != std::string::npos )
                {

                 if (n == std::string::npos){

                      string s = transform(slovo);
                      cout << s << endl;

                      }else{
                      string s = untransform(slovo);
                      cout << s << endl;

                      }
                }else{
            cout << "chyba" << endl;

         } 
         }
```

EDIT2:

```
cin >> slovo;
             }      
             std::string::size_type n;
             std::string const ss = slovo;

             n  = ss.find('_');

             // kontrola podtrznika

           if ( ss.empty() && ss[0] == '_' && ss[ss.length() - 1] == '_' )
           {
            cout << "chyba" << endl;
            }

           if ( ss.length() > 3 && ss.find( "__", 1, ss.length() - 2 ) != std::string::npos )
           {
            cout << "chyba" << endl;
            }

             if (n == std::string::npos)
                 {
                  string s = transform(slovo);
                  cout << s << endl;

                  }else{
                  string s = untransform(slovo);
                  cout << s << endl;
                 }
```

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `n` and `n2`?

Comment: "_ cannot be in front of capital letter" - if you're using find('_') etc. to locate the underscores, you'll have to use a loop to find each one then check if it's followed by a letter; your code lacks a loop so there's no way it can work... maybe try adding that and edit in the new code?

Answer (score 2):

if those functions return `npos` it means the character couldn't be found in the string. So if one of them returns that, all 3 of them will.

So this code outputs 'chyba' it there's no `_` in the string or calls `untransform` otherwise. From your description, that's not what you intend.

You really need to scan through the string for all those conditions. And if you want to check the first and last characters of the string, use `ss[0]` and `ss[ss.length() - 1]` (taking appropriate care you don't have a string of length 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that the two function calls will give you the same result

```
         n  = ss.find('_');
         n2 = ss.find_first_of('_');
```

In this context they are equivalent.

If I have understood you correctly you need to determine whether the first and the last characters in a string are underscores and whether the string contains two adjacent undescores within itself.

To determine the first case it is simple to write

```
if ( !ss.empty() && ss.front() == '_' && ss.back() == '_' )
{
//...
}
```

To find at least two adjacent underscores excluding the first and the last characters you can write

```
if ( ss.length() > 3 && ss.find( "__", 1, ss.length() - 2 ) != std::string::npos )
{
//...
}
```

Comment: see my edit, im getting error on front and back, const struct std::string' has no member named 'back' and invalid conversion from int to char in the second condition..

Comment: It seems you have an old compiler. Change ss.front() and ss.back() to ss[0] and ss[ss.length() - 1]

Comment: now im getting error in the second if condition, ... invalid conversion from `int' to `const char*'

Comment: I had a typo. You must use double quotes "__" when two undescores are searched.

Comment: check my code now, Im little confused by all of those conditions, im getting Chyba every time

Comment: Where do you have taken n from in this statement if (n == std::string::npos)? It is enough the two condition I showed. The first one checks whether the string starts from underscore and ends with underscore, The second condition determinates whether there are two adjacent underscores.

Comment: yes but the condition n==std:string... is required for transform and untransform functions, cause if it finds a underscore in a string, it is supposed to run one of those functions

Comment: When write instead if ( ss.length() > 3 && ( n = ss.find( "__", 1, ss.length() - 2 ) ) != std::string::npos )

Comment: would you please edit your code above ? im freaking confused now :D please

Comment: I think the problem is not in these details. You should redesign your code in whole. As for me I do not understand for example what meaning of n or why these two conditions are nested and so on.

Comment: check my code now, functions you suggested to use doesnt work at all in here..im getting still the same as before, i can add underscore _lol_ and it doesnt show error, etc..

Comment: Here must be if ( !ss.empty() && ss[0] == '_' && ss[ss.length() - 1] == '_' ) that is !ss.empty() with the exclamation sign

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46676/discussion-between-feri-and-vlad-from-moscow)

Comment: okay, then lets solve it here, .. im not getting chyba when I type `lol_Lol, lol__lol, _lol, lol_` and I should. I get chyba only when `_lol_`